# Does .net compact framework application can run on windows 8

Tags: .net, mobile, windows-mobile

Can I install application developed in .NET compact framework (windows Mobile 6.5) or Windows CE to run on latest windows 8 phones or tablet?

Comment: Perhaps you could mark @Reed's as the answer on this one?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 both have their own runtime and API.  If you want your application to run on Windows Phone 8 or on Windows 8 RT, you will need to develop specifically for those platforms.

Luckily, they do support a richer programming model than the .NET CF, so the port of the logic portion of your application should be fairly smooth.  The UI uses a completely different model, as it's now completely XAML based, and will likely need to be completely rewritten.